# Como implementar server side processing en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, registro, server-side-rendering

que tal? Estoy tratando de implementar server side processing en codeigniter y tengo un problema a nivel del controlador, ya que en mi código es el encargado de cargar las vistas, como verán a continuación:

[image]

Cuando intento hacer el llamado de las columnas de mi tabla como dice la documentación de datatable para server side, no me cargan bien las vistas, los datos los trae en formato json y las carga fuera de las tablas ya que como verán mis vistas se cargan por partes desde mi función index y luego se carga el listado de datos.

Esta es una parte de la vista para que puedan entender un poco mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el modelo no habría problema ya que la consulta esta bien, seguí los pasos de la documentación cambiando sacando el tbody y armando el ajax y cuando llego al controlador para llamar a los datos tengo ese problema debido a la forma en que se cargan las vistas; solo quiero implementar server side processing y estoy viendo alternativas para no tener que modificar todo mi código.

Acepto todas sus ideas y sugerencias, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:

```
print_r($this->load->view('listado'......))
```

Esto te debería imprimir correctamente la tabla con los datos que le pasaste del modelo (`$listado_data`).

Comenta lo demás y vas descartando donde esta el problema. Publica como se muestran los datos en el navegador.